# Adding a field of type metadata with powershell

Tags: powershell, column, managed-metadata

I'm trying to add a column of type Metadata. I've first exported the SchemaXml of an existing column on which i'm working. After that I added the column with method AddAsSchemaXml.

The field is here, and I can see that it has choosen the right metadata. My problem is that when I try to add an item, the field doesn't want to save.

Do you have any ideas where it comes from ?

Comment: what kind of error do you get when you save? Please paste your XML at the question too. Also try to avoid comments in your XML or parsing will fail

Comment: Hey I've succeed managing that by modifying my powershell function. I look if the type of my field is metadata, and then I add the metadata not with the AddFieldAsXml function but create the field with Fields.Add()
Thanks

Comment: If that was the answer, create an answer and mark as answer (might take a few days before you can mark as answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've succeed managing that by modifying my powershell function.
I look if the type of my field is metadata, and then I add the metadata not with the AddFieldAsXml function but create the field with Fields.Add()

Thanks